# How to create domain based email address with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns

I have a domain for example 'abc.com' routed to website hosted on AWS instance and working fine.

Now what are the steps to create domain based email addresses for example saif@abc.com and amaan@abc.com?

I am using Amazon AWS.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a domain for example 'abc.com' routed to website hosted on AWS

Does that mean that your domain is registered to AWS and is available in Route 53? Or is your domain registered with another registrar? e.g. GoDaddy, Google Domains, etc.

If AWS is your registrar, take a look at the [Amazon SES Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html).
 Specifically, the [Amazon SES Quick Start Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/quick-start.html) to get up and running quickly.

If AWS is not your registrar, you can either set up your email through your registrar, or you can update your DNS records to use AWS SES. See [Verifying Domains in SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html) in the developer guide linked above.

Cheers!

Comment: For routing i am using cloudflare. i have updated the txt and mx records in DNS pointing to my aws instance.
i have redirected the emails to ses bucket now but how these emails will be viewed